# How to find control characters in a file?

Tags: grep, control-characters

I want to find what control characters are in my file. I do not search for specific character, but it is possible `\t` or `\n`. I have a program that is telling me: `Invalid control character`. But when I open the file I do not see anything. How to show these characters? I suspect `\n` or `\t` or some characters that adds spaces.

I tried: `grep '\n' myfile.txt` But in the output it marked the `n` letter.

Comment: Hi! I think you can probably have some control characters in your file, is [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/) helpful somehow?

Comment: Is this question somehow different from your other question? [How to find and replace seemingly a tab char using sed?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/518984)  It would help if you told us what program it is that is complaining (a "control character" could potentially be a character with some specific semantics when used with your program, not necessarily an ASCII _control character_).

Answer (score 3):

**To look for a specific character**

`grep` and `sed` don't support backslash notation for control characters. (`sed` does use backslash for regexp *backreferences*.) If you are using `bash` *it* can convert a backslash sequence to the actual control character before passing to these (or any) programs:

```
$ grep $'\t' file
$ sed -n /$'\t'/p file
$ # or change to l (ell) to visibly show the control character(s)
$ sed -n /$'\t'/l file
```

OTOH `awk` does portably support this notation:

```
$ awk '/\t/' file
```

**To look for any control character**

Both `grep` and `sed` can search for a complemented character class/range, which will find lines containing *any* character that is not a 'printable' (graphic or space) ASCII character. (The newline characters which separate lines in the file are not treated as *in* the lines, and thus do not satisfy this match. However, if you have a file with Windows or telnet/SMTP/etc style CRLF, the CR *will* match on every line, making this technique less useful.)

```
 $ export LANG=C # use an ASCII or at least single-byte locale; this is the simplest one
 $ grep '[^ -~]' file
 $ sed -n '/[^ -~]/p' file
 $ # or better (see below)
 $ sed -n '/[^ -~]/l' file
```

To *display* which control character(s) is(are) present, in either the whole file or selected line(s), in addition to the [options given by SHawarden](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518974/#518994) you can also use:

```
 $ sed -n l [file] # that's ell not one; can merge into the selection as above
 $ cat -vT [file]
 $ # both read stdin if not given a filename 
 $ # and thus can be piped from a selection command above
```

Note some of these displays use backslash notation for at least *some* characters (`\t` = tab, `\b` = backspace) while others use 'caret' (which in ancient times was 'uparrow') notation (`^I` = tab, `^H` = backspace). See any ASCII chart for the correspondences, noting that caret/uparrow represents either subtracting or adding hex 40 (equal to octal 100).

Answer (score 1):

To see what that character is:

```
less sourcefile
```

or

```
od -c sourceFile
```

for a more verbose view.

Comment: `less -r` is the opposite of what is wanted here; it doesn't show _any_ control chars. `less` _without_ `-r` does show _most_ -- but not tab (wanted here) and backspace.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's about json data (python's `json` package is known to report that error message), you could identify which json string has control characters in them with:

```
perl -Mcharnames=:full -C -l -0777 -ne '
  while (/"(?:\\.|[^"])*"/g) {
    my $offset = $-[0];
    my $string = $&;
    @ctrl = map {charnames::viacode(ord($_))} $string =~ /\p{PosixCntrl}/g;
    if (@ctrl) {
       print "Offset: $offset, String: $string, Ctrl: ". join "+", @ctrl
    }
  }' file.json
```

On an example `file.json` file here:

```
$ python -c 'import json; import os; print(json.load(file("file.json")))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 22 (char 21)
```

And the `perl` code above returns:

```
Offset: 19, String: "a  b
c", Ctrl: CHARACTER TABULATION+LINE FEED
```

You can see the control character python complains about is that TAB one, 2 chars after the start of that `"..."` string. Note that `perl` reports the offsite in number of characters, while python reports  them in number of bytes.